# How to correctly position a set of cuboids based on a direction property in MonoGame

Tags: monogame, geometry, orientation, position

I am trying to create a map for my game using a list of cuboid sections that are defined like this:

```
[{ 
    Position: new Vector3(0, 0, 0), 
    Size: new Vector3(6f, 100f, 0.1f), 
    Direction = Vector3.Forward
 },
 {  
    Size: new Vector3(6f, 100f, 0.1f), 
    Direction = Vector3.Right
 },
 {  
    Size: new Vector3(6f, 100f, 0.1f), 
    Direction = Vector3.Right
 },
 {  
    Size: new Vector3(6f, 100f, 0.1f), 
    Direction = Vector3.Left
 }]
```

Note that only the first section has a position coordinate. After enumerating these values I am aiming to end up with a map that looks like this.

[image: Expected result]

I've gotten as far as this code which solves some of the problem, but I can't wrap my head around how to get it to work taking into account the prior cubes orientation.

```
var v = new Vector3((0.5f * (x1 - x2)) + priorSection.Position.Value.X, 0, (-0.5f * (y1 + y2)) + priorSection.Position.Value.Z);
```

I am stuck. The problem that I run into is that the concept of left and right is relative to the orientation of the prior section of the map and I can't work out how to calculate the coordinates of each section based on the orientation and position of the prior section.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

1. Adding vectors geometrically 'concatenates' them, lays them end-to-end.
2. Rotating the rectangle simply swaps the x and y values, so a vertical rectangle of size {6f, 100f} becomes horizontal rectangle of size {100f, 6f}.

*Assuming down is negative values of Y (if not, simply negate the Y value)*

The top right corner of the first rectangle is the centroid plus half the size, so {0f + 3f, 0f - 50f} = {3f, -50f}.
The bottom left corner of the second rectangle (the only one touching the first one) is {3f, -50f + 6f} = {3f, -44f}. This shifting factor is determined by its being aligned to the top of the last rectangle.
So, the centroid (center point) of the second rectangle is simply this plus half the rotated size of the second rectangle:
{3f + 50f, -44f - 3f} = **{53f, -47f}**

So, the centroid of each next rectangle is half of the rotated size of the previous rectangle plus a shifting factor and plus half of its own rotated size.